# Enable Web Tours for Public and Portal Users Odoo V15 Community

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

I'm running Odoo V15 Community. I recently implemented web tours on specific website pages. However, the tours are available only to internal users.

**Please is it possible to enable tours for portal and public users?**

If not, are there any modifications which could be done to do so?

I tried adding my custom tour JavaScript file to the front-end assets directory, but tours still couldn't be accessed by public and portal users.